# iPhone IOS 6.0.1 'Take Photo' image corrupted in Canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, html, canvas

I currently have a canvas html5 element setup to receive an uploaded image, resize it, and pass its data uri to a form value which is then submitted to the server. This works well on computers but has run into a problem when I tested it on my iPhone through Safari.

With the new IOS 6.0.1 update when uploading an image I can choose 'Take Photo or Video', however two issues arise when doing so from an iPhone (i do not have an iPad handy to test :( )...

1) The image is either appears squished or "unfinished" as in the top 1/3 of the image is all that remains

- I removed my context.scale() function and these issues did not
  appear. Is there some   processing limitation for scaling on iphone
  devices? A simple context.scale(0.5, 0.5) does not seem to work.

2) The image is rotated (this problem persists when context.scale() is removed).

- I've read that image may preserve some of its orientation data, but how would one remove that?

These issues seem isolated to only when I 'Take Photo' or use an image that my iPhone took. When using images downloaded from my computer onto my iPhone there seems to be no problem for either issues 1) or 2). Also when using pictures taken by my iPhone, sent to my computer, and then uploaded from the computer there seems to be no problems as well.

For issue 1) since the same picture is used by my computer (no problems) and iPhone (problem) I venture to guess it is a iPhone limitation for context.scale(), unless when sending an image by email my iPhone compresses it somehow and removes the orientation data which is also not a problem when used by my computer. As you can see I'm quite confused! Thanks for any help!

my code for canvas resizing...

```
        reader.onload = function(e) {
      preview.html('<img id="scream" src="' + e.target.result + '" ' + (preview.css('max-height') != 'none' ? 'style="max-height: ' + preview.css('max-height') + ';"' : '') + ' />')
      element.addClass('fileupload-exists').removeClass('fileupload-new')

      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
          context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
          image = new Image();

      image.onload = function () {
          var img = this,
              width = img.width,
              height = img.height;

          canvas.width = 300;
          canvas.height = 300;

          context.scale(0.25, 0.25);
          context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
          //console.log(base64);

          //$('form_6').val(base64);

          document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      };
      image.src = e.target.result;

    }
```